# Why is this item showing up in the Software Center when it doesn't exist?

Tags: installation, software-center, package-management

Here is an item in the Software Center:

[image]

Here is what happens when I click "More Info":

[image]

Why is it showing up if it doesn't exist?

Comment: When I click *More Info* I get the correct page...try refreshing your apt cache.

Comment: @DoR: Nope. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The message is saying that the 'Software Sources' that you have given it permissions to install from don't include the software. What it isn't telling you is that it is available from another software source. The 'More Info' button in Natty gives you a better message:
[image: software source message in Natty]

The application is in the Multiverse source, and you can enable that by going to Edit > Software Sources and ticking the 'Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)' checkbox.

Comment: I *do* have Multiverse enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad went down a little while ago - maintenance, maybe. When I checked to see if I could replicate your problem, I also checked launchpad again. Launchpad is now up (at this point in time, at least) and I can fully load that app with no problems.

I'm betting you hit the server when it wasn't listening. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely it is showing up as existing but in reality does not (such as if you changed your mirrors (like when you choose the fastest available), or if the package does not exist for your architecture.